# Css background not appearing with external stylesheet?

Tags: css

When the styles were just listed on the page everything worked fine.
Now I made it an external stylesheet and everything still works, except for the background.
The image is located in resources.
Should the url be changed? I tried adding resources/ or putting it in a folder but nothing seems to work...

```
body{
    background-image:url(background.jpg);
    background-attachment:fixed;
    color: white;
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    /*font-size: 1.52em;*/
}
```

It's for a school project and I'd really appreciate help on this...

Comment: You need to change the url of your `background-image`

Comment: This problem is totally unrelated to Java and JSF.

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought it might make a difference knowing i was using JSF

Comment: Use firebug to see if the image is actually loading or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your stylesheet is loaded using `<h:outputStylesheet>`, you cannot refer to a bundled image that way.  Use the built-in `resource` Map instead:

```
background-image: url("#{resource['myImages:background.jpg']}");
```

(assuming your images are in the `resources/myImages` directory).

Comment: I wasn't using <h:outputStylesheet>... but I am now^^ This fixed it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You should change the URL. If your image is in site root > img > imagefile and the html is in root and your css is in root > css > cssfile then you should use

```
background-image: url(../img/imagefile)
```

Comment: the image is in the root. This worked when it was an internal stylesheet.